# Displaying mht file in iframe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe, mhtml

I need to display mht file stored in zip archive in frame on the page

```
  <iframe src="@Url.Action("LoadInstrucion","Pharmacy", new {id= Model.Instrukciya })"></iframe>
```

Action in MVC Controller returning file

```
public ActionResult LoadInstrucion(string id)
{
  var bytes = InstructionsLoader.LoadInstrucion(id);
  return File(bytes, "multipart/related");
}
```

Action for getting byte array from file

```cs
public static byte[] LoadInstrucion(string zipFileName)
{
    string zipfilePath = $@"{HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath}Content\inst\{zipFileName}.zip";
    if (File.Exists(zipfilePath))
    {
        using (var zipStream = new FileStream(zipfilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        {
            if (archive.Entries.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = archive.Entries[0];
                var stream = file.Open();
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                  stream.CopyTo(ms);
                  return  ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

If I navigate to Url I see the requested mht file, but it is not displayed in iframe. In Dev console I get warning:

> Attempted to load a multipart archive into an subframe